# Recursive object setting java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a model call Section. This section has 2 fields: color and a list of Section objects.

```
public class Section{
    public String color;
    public List<Section> sub_sections;


}
```

Suppose I get a Json feed with a List of Section objects. Within each Section object is a color field set to a random color and another list of Section objects. Within these nested Section lists the color fields are set to an empty string. We dont know how many nested Sections there are.

How do i set all nested color Strings within the nested Sections to be the same as the color from the first level section? My code below is non recursive for 3 levels deep to give you an ides of the problem.

```
for(Section section : sectionsList){
        for(Section sub : section.sub_sections){
            sub.color=section.color;
            if(sub.sub_sections.size()> 0){
                for(Section sub2 : sub.sub_sections){
                    sub2.color=sub.color;
                    if(sub2.sub_sections.size()> 0){
                        for(Section sub3 : sub2.sub_sections){
                            sub3.color=sub2.color;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would be your base case? What would be your recursive case?

Comment: The base case would probably be section.subsections.size() = 0. What do you mean by the recursive case?

Comment: Under which conditions would you recursively call the method on the `sub_sections`?

Comment: you would only call the sub_sections of a section if they exist, otherwise you break out of the algorithm. I had somethinbg like this in mine but its not right  public Section recSection(Section section){

        if(section.sub_sections==null){
            return section;
        }
        else{
            for(Section sec : section.sub_sections){
                sec.color = section.color;
            }

            return recSection()
        }
    }

Comment: Rule 1 of recursive algorithms is: stop condition!  Instead of for in for in for ... you need a recursive method call which has a stop condition.

Comment: @tom thats what he asked for, imho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you, this may be a solution. You need a public starting method without parameters and a recursive method which gets the original color to set.

```
public class Section{
  public String color;
  public List<Section> sub_sections;

  /** Propagates the current section color to all sub sections. */
  public void propagate() {
    propagate(this.color);
  }

  /** Propagates the passed color to this section and all sub sections recursively. */
  private void propagate(String propagatedColor) {
    color = propagatedColor;
    for (Section sub : sub_sections) {
      sub.propagate(propagatedColor);
    }
  }

}
```

Than your usage code will look like:

```
for (Section section : sectionsList) {
  section.propagate();
}
```

Comment: then how do i cal that? for(Section sec : sectionList){ sec.propogate(color) }. Does that work through all levels?

Comment: @sirFunkenstine if you have any section instance, just call section.propagate(). Yes, it work through all levels starting at the one you called propagate().

Answer (score 2):

if i unserstand you, then some thing like this could be a solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Section{
    public String color;
    public List<Section> sub_sections;

    public Section(String color,List<Section> subs){
        this.color = color;
        this.sub_sesctions = subs;
    }

    public static List<Section> init(List<Section> sectionsList){
        List<Section> all = new ArrayList<Section>();
        for(Section section : sectionsList){
            List<Section> subs = initRec(section.sub_sections, section.color);
            all.add(new Section(section.color,subs));
        } 
        return all;
    }

    private List<Section> initRec(List<Section> sectionsList, String color){
        List<Section> subs = new ArrayList<Section>();
        for(Section sub : sectionsList){           
            subs.add( new Section(color, initRec(sub.sub_sections, color) ) );
        }
        return subs;
    }


}
```

you beginn with calling `init(List<Section> sectionsList)`

**UPDATE** : i updated the contructor

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
void setColor(Section s){
    //Loop through all subsections
    for(Section sub:s){
        //Set each child subsection to parent color
        sub.color = s.color;
        //Check if child subsection has more children
        if(sub.sub_sections.size() > 0){
            //If it does treat the child as a parent and feed it back into the method
            setColor(sub);
        }
        //If it has no more children, method returns and propagates back up the stack.
    }
}
```

Haven't tested this but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setTopLevelColor(String topLevelColor) {
    this.color = topLevelColor;
    if(this.sub_sections.size() > 0) {
        for(Section sub : this.sub_sections) {
            sub.setTopLevelColor(topLevelColor);
        }
    }
}
```